# how to invoke a method in java from another class by obtaining the method name as a string from the result obtained from a query

Tags: java

I am trying to invoke method from another class by specifying the method name. The method name is received from the result obtained from a query...

**Class:VAL**

```
ps1=connection.prepareStatement("select method_name from validation where tablename=? and type_name=?");
ps1.setString(1, "table_name");
ps1.setString(2, "fieldtype");
ResultSet rs1 = null;
rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
while(rs1.next())
{
methname=rs1.getString(1);
}
rs1.close();
return status;
```

Now I should use this method name  suppose if its methname="Alphanumeric" I should call this method written in class Special_validation from class VAL.

**Class:Special_validation**

```
Class Special_validation
{
public boolean Alphanumeric()
{
------
------
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use java reflection.

A call to Class.getDeclaredMethod() would return a Method. You could use Method.invoke() to call this method.

You might also want to get function prototype, not just the name, before calling getDeclaredMethod()

[Reference](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/java-reflection-tutorial/)

Comment: Class c=Class.forName("utility.Special_validation");
    Method m=c.getDeclaredMethod("cAlphaSpace");
    Object t = c.newInstance();
    Object o= m.invoke(t);   . I tried using this..my method name is cAlphaSpace.. but receives error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: utility.Special_validation.cAlphaSpace()
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)...

Comment: Can you post the actual declaration of method? There may be more than one methods by same name, and so, to actually retrieve a specific method, you should provide its full prototype. Is your target method inherited or private? Also, try calling getDeclaredMethods() and see if your target method is in the returned array